# How to prepend HTML `<li>` to `<ul>` using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to append an `<li>` element to multiple `<ul>` using a `for-loop` in jQuery.

Code Snippet:

JQuery:

```
var lists = $('ul.menu');

for(var i=0; i<lists.length; i++){
    var lnk = "<li>All</li>";
    lnk = $('<div />').html(lnk).text();
    lists[i].prepend(lnk);
}
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
    <li>Graphics</li>
    <li>Videos</li>
    <li>Programming</li>
</ul>
<hr>
<ul class="menu">
    <li>Our Story</li>
    <li>About Us</li>
</ul>
```

As per code `<li>` inserts as the proper text, but is been formatted as plain text instead of an `<li>`.

What am I doing wrong? How to correct my mistakes?

Comment: Not able to replicate

Comment: Why are you doing `lnk = $('<div />').html(lnk).text();`? It seems like you probably have a reason for that, but it's not clear what it is. (Genuinely.)

Comment: In light of your answer, I've removed that line and the code works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling the raw DOM `prepend` (which only exists on modern browsers), because `lists[i]` accesses the raw `ul` element. You're also just taking the *text* of what you want to prepend, rather than including any `li` markup. You probably want to:

1. Call jQuery's `prepend`, and
2. Include the `li` in what you're prepending

Example:

```js
var lists = $('ul.menu');

for(var i=0; i<lists.length; i++){
 var lnk = "<li>All</li>";
 lists.eq(i).prepend(lnk);
}
```

```css
/* No CSS */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
 <li>Graphics</li>
 <li>Videos</li>
 <li>Programming</li>
</ul>
<hr>
<ul class="menu">
 <li>Our Story</li>
 <li>About Us</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

A slightly more jQuery-ish alternative to [TJ Crowder's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52247384/746736)...

```js
$('ul.menu').each(function() {
    $(this).prepend("<li>All</li>");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
    <li>Graphics</li>
    <li>Videos</li>
    <li>Programming</li>
</ul>
<hr>
<ul class="menu">
    <li>Our Story</li>
    <li>About Us</li>
</ul>
```